# Does this function add new node to the end of the linked list?

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, insert, singly-linked-list

I wonder, does this insert a node to the end of the list? Let's say that I have a linked list of 1->2->3->8->NULL and I want to insert a new node with data of 9. It will traverse to NULL recursively. When head is pointing at NULL, head = nextNode is not working. Or is head still pointing at node of 8? Thank you.

I only want to know can this insert a node at the end of the list? I don't think so.

```
void insert(Node *&head, int data) {
    if (head == NULL || data <head ->data) {
        Node *nextNode = new Node;
        nextNode->data = data;
        nextNode->next = head;
        head= nextNode;
    } else {
        insert(head->next, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can insert a node to the end of the list. Try it out yourself in the link in my answer.

Comment: Perhaps the confusing part about the function is the name of the argument `head`. It is not the head of the list except on the first iteration.

Answer (score 2):

this function is completely wrong cos it will cause memory leakage. and it will only work for first iteration.
I am writing u the code but it wont help u learn.

```
if(head==NULL)
{
    Node *nxtNode=new Node;
    nxtNode->data=data;
    head=nxtNode;
    nxtNode->next=NULL;
    return;
}
if(head->next==NULL||data<head->next->data)
{
    Node *nxtNode=new Node;
    nxtNode->data=data;
    nxtNode->next=head->next;
    head->next=nxtNode->next;
    return;
}
else
{
    insert(head->next,data);
}
```

Comment: your function is making lots of dangling pointers right now

Comment: The code doesn't leak memory. There should be a destructor for the class that traverses the list and deallocates it. The function also seems to work just fine.

Comment: @okovko  there is no indication of that , also traversing destructor if fine only in there is list class wrapping around nodes. Doing that in node is to invite stack overflow

Comment: @IbrahimTariqGujjar It is time to learn singly-linked lists and references.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I have to wonder why most of single-linked list questions, this included, on SO are based on rather ancient text book example of 90-91, which essentially no different from C implementation

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie And moreover they use the so-called Java approach (it is my term) where you can not use for example pointer to pointer. So the logic is separated into whether the node is the head node equal to NULL or the head node is not equal to NULL.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `*&head` that's what points me to that book, I owned one actually, from AT&T library series reprinted by "ДиаСофт", as either early Straustroup or Paul Lucas

Comment: my code will work perfect tho now i understand he is using *& that is why he is doing it.but I feel uneasy whenever i do that.

Answer (score 1):

This condition

```
if ( head == NULL || data < head->data )
```

is not evaluates to true for each node in the list that contains the sequence of nodes like

```
1->2->3->8->NULL
```

because the value of data `9` is not less than any value of data of existent nodes.

So the function will be recursively called until the next node will be equal to NULL (that is when the function will be called with reference to the data member next of the last node that is equal to nullptr). As a result the new node is appended to the tail of the list. That is the last pointer in the list with the value NULL will be substituted for the new node. Thus nodes are inserted in the list in the ascending order.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void insert( Node * &head, int data ) 
{
    if ( head == nullptr || data < head ->data ) 
    {
        head = new Node { data, head };
    } 
    else 
    {
        insert( head->next, data );
    }
}

std::ostream & output( const Node *head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( ; head != nullptr; head = head->next)
    {
        os << head->data << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

int main() 
{
    Node *head = nullptr;

    for ( int data : { 3, 8, 1, 2, 9 } )
    {
        insert( head, data );
        output( head ) << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
3 -> null
3 -> 8 -> null
1 -> 3 -> 8 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> null
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
```

To make it clear consider a list that contains two nodes with data `1` and `3`.

```
head  |node A with value 1|next B|  |node B with value 3| next nullptr|
 |______________|              |______________|
```

and you are trying to insert a node with the value `2`.

The function is called with

```
insert( head, 2 );
```

head->data equal to 1 is not greater than 2. SO the function is called like

```
insert( ( node A )->next, 2 );
```

( node A )->next->data equal to 3 is greater than 2.

So you have to substitute ( node A )->next with the address of the newly created node with the value 2.

```
head  |node A with value 1|next C|  |node B with value 3| next nullptr|
 |______________|              |              |
                               |              |
          |node C with value 2 | the value of next B of node A|
```

Comment: what I don't get is if the pointer is pointing to the NULL, nextNode will point to NULL. Then, NULL is pointing to nextNode?

Comment: @HageNezz The data member next of the node with the value 8 will have NULL. This data member is substituted by the new created node and the data member next of this created node sets to the previous value of the data member next of the node with the value 8 that is by NULL. So the appended node will be the last node of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It inserts a new node into the linked list into the sorted position. At least, that is the intent.

Here is the compiled code working with input that demonstrates the behavior: [link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jiQEnVlxLW8KB6dN).

The line of interest: `if (head == NULL || data < head->data)`

The new entry is placed in the position that this condition passes.